# Resolve an IFrame serverside

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to resolve an Iframe server side and then display the page as the server would see it?

I have a company intranet and an extranet, and as part of some upcoming work, a page that is on the intranet needs to be made accessible externally through the extranet portal.

This internal page is quite complex and is subject to change, so this isn't something that i want to duplicate for the purpose of making it available.

i did search for answers online, but im fairly new to Asp.net, so i'm unsure how to word this to get good results.

Any other, better, suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: sure, but you'd have to set up a full proxy, which means rewriting the html so that any resource references (script src, img src, yada yada yada) all point back to your proxy page instead of whatever resource they originally pointed at.

Comment: Hi Marc, i guess that is a valid option, but i don't have a access to change the internal page as that project is run by another person unfortunately. i would be looking to use their existing page and display it externally without changing their code. Thanks for your response anyway :)